# Perl Tumblr Module Proxy

Tags: perl, module, tumblr

I'm using this https://github.com/damog/www-tumblr Module to manage some of my bigger Tumblr Accounts.

Everything is working greate, but now i want to add more then just 3 Tumblr Accounts and manage them trought the Tumblr Api, because managing every Account on his own will cost me about 2 Hours every Day.

Tumblr don't allow multiple accounts so i would like to use some http proxy to hide the requests.

How can i add Proxy Support to this Module http://search.cpan.org/~damog/WWW-Tumblr-5.00/lib/WWW/Tumblr.pm

Hope someone can help me. Kind regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick glance at source shows that instances have undocumented `ua` property that contains instance of [`LWP::UserAgent`](http://p3rl.org/LWP::UserAgent) object used to perform actual requests. You can configure it however you like.

For example:

```
$my_www_tumblr->ua->proxy(['http', 'ftp'], 'http://example.com/');
```